# How create django-cms plugin from django views?

Tags: django, django-cms

I created a "view" of the "model" which showing the last five elements. How I can create CMS plugin, that I could put into "placeholder"?

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by a CMS plugin. It's very unclear.

Comment: I may be stupid, or do not quite understand what requires plugins django-cms, or Google Translate screwed up and you did not understand what I want. I want to do the thing that allows me to put in a "placeholder" last 5 added to the database records.

Comment: Like recent blog entries.

Comment: At last I understand!!! Sorry for the stupid question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to create a plugin for django-cms that can be used inside a placeholder, you [have to create a subclass of CMSPluginBase](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/extending_cms/extending_examples.html#the-plugin-class). Within your subclass you should override the **render** method, to implement your custom rendering.

See also this example (taken from the documentation):

```
# myapp/cms_plugins.py
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from polls.models import PollPlugin as PollPluginModel
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class PollPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = PollPluginModel # Model where data about this plugin is saved
    name = _("Poll Plugin") # Name of the plugin
    render_template = "polls/plugin.html" # template to render the plugin with

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({'instance':instance})
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(PollPlugin) # register the plugin
```